# bubble sort in C issue

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

Hello I'm trying to get my program to arrange numbers into ascending order.

It first list the numbers you enter(up to 20) it then removes any duplicates and list them. Then I need them to get listed in ascending ordering using a bubble sort. Can anyone help me with that last part?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main (void)

{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    int nums[20] , i , j, k, swap ;
    int count=0;

    {
        printf("Enter integers. (Negative -1 to stop):\n");
        for (i=0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
            count = count +1;

            if(nums[i] == -1 )

            break;
        }
    }

    printf("The numbers you entered are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<count;++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Your numbers with the duplicate numbers removed:\n ");

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<count;)
        {
            if(nums[j]==nums[i])
            {
                for(k=j;k<count-1;++k)
                {
                    nums[k]=nums[k+1];
                }
                count--;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("%d\n ",nums[i]);

    for(i=0; i<(k-1); i++)
    {
        for(i=0; i < k-j; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] > nums[i+1])
            {
                swap = nums[i];
                nums[i] =nums[i+1];
                nums[i+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n Your numbers sorted in to ascending order:\n");

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        printf("%d\n ",nums[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want bubble sort algorithm?

Comment: Indent your code properly and you will find the issue. There is an empty loop because a misplaced brace.

Comment: checking for duplicates if you do after sorting it will be easier if thats fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bubble sort in the code is:

```
for(i=0; i<(k-1); i++)
{
  for(i=0; i < k-j; i++)
  {
  }
    if (nums[i] > nums[i+1])
    {
       swap = nums[i];
       nums[i] =nums[i+1];
       nums[i+1] = swap;
    }
}
```

Assuming `k` is the number of elements to sort, it should be:

```
for(i=0; i<(k-1); i++)
{
  for(j=0; j < k - 1 - i; j++)
  {
    if (nums[j] > nums[j+1])
    {
       swap = nums[j];
       nums[j] =nums[j+1];
       nums[j+1] = swap;
    }
}
```

Your code had the second loop with an empty body and you need a diffrent loop variable for the inner loop than `i`, since this is driving the outer loop.

Comment: I tried this and it just prints out the highest number over and over. I'm not sure if K is the number of elements to sort. The bubble sort comes right after the duplicates are removed.

Comment: nevermind I fixed it. I forgot to change                  for(j=0;j<i;j++)
printf("%d\n ",nums[i] <<< chnaged to nums[j] and it works. ty for the help

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort part

```
for(i=0; i<(k-1); i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < k-i; j++)
    {

   if (nums[j] > nums[j+1])
    {
      swap = nums[j];
      nums[j] =nums[j+1];
      nums[j+1] = swap;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: This works but the issue I'm having now is the last number in the bubble sort is getting removed. For example after duplicates are removed i'm left with 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and the ascending order list will show them all in order except the last number. in my case that was 9